# Merge raster tiles with different resolution and keep original resolution using Python

Tags: raster, resolution, gdal-merge

### Problem

I have two raster images with different size and resolution, which are overlapping and which I'd like to merge. The smaller image has a higher resolution which I want to merge into the larger image with the lower resolution. However, I don't want to resample the low resolution raster tile, but keep the origin resolution in the area where no overlapping exists.

### Information

Some information about the two tiles:

first image (small, high resolution):

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /home/Downloads/srtm_38_03/srtm_38_03.tif
Size is 6000, 6000

Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
DATUM["WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]

Origin = (5.000000000000000,50.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.000833333333333,-0.000833333333333)
Metadata:
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left ( 5.0000000, 50.0000000) ( 5d 0' 0.00"E, 50d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left ( 5.0000000, 45.0000000) ( 5d 0' 0.00"E, 45d 0' 0.00"N)
Upper Right ( 10.0000000, 50.0000000) ( 10d 0' 0.00"E, 50d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 10.0000000, 45.0000000) ( 10d 0' 0.00"E, 45d 0' 0.00"N)
Center ( 7.5000000, 47.5000000) ( 7d30' 0.00"E, 47d30' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=6000x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
NoData Value=-32768
```

second image (large, low resolution):

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /home/Downloads/tiles/30N000E_20101117_gmted_mea075.tif
Size is 14400, 9600

Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
DATUM["WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]

Origin = (-0.000138888888889,49.999861111111109)
Pixel Size = (0.002083333333333,-0.002083333333333)
Metadata:
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left ( -0.0001389, 49.9998611) ( 0d 0' 0.50"W, 49d59'59.50"N)
Lower Left ( -0.0001389, 29.9998611) ( 0d 0' 0.50"W, 29d59'59.50"N)
Upper Right ( 29.9998611, 49.9998611) ( 29d59'59.50"E, 49d59'59.50"N)
Lower Right ( 29.9998611, 29.9998611) ( 29d59'59.50"E, 29d59'59.50"N)
Center ( 14.9998611, 39.9998611) ( 14d59'59.50"E, 39d59'59.50"N)
Band 1 Block=14400x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
Min=-81.000 Max=4712.000 
Minimum=-81.000, Maximum=4712.000, Mean=284.827, StdDev=414.286
NoData Value=-32768
Metadata:
STATISTICS_EXCLUDEDVALUES=-32768
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=4712
STATISTICS_MEAN=284.8270891059
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-81
STATISTICS_STDDEV=414.28584583842
```

The image shows the two raster tiles. The orange box is just for orientation where the smaller tile is localized.

[image: localization]

This image cutout shows the two different resolutions at the tiles border which I want to keep in the merged tile.

[image: cutout]

### What did I try so far?

> [gdal_merge](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html): This utility will automatically mosaic a set of images. All the images must be in the same coordinate system and have a matching number of bands, but they may be overlapping, and at different resolutions. **In areas of overlap, the last image will be copied over earlier ones**.

I used `gdal_merge.py` in the following way:

`/usr/bin/gdal_merge.py -o /home/Workspace/output.tif 30N000E_20101117_gmted_mea075.tif srtm_38_03.tif`

which results in an image identical to `30N000E_20101117_gmted_mea075.tif` with no change at all.

Using it with the images switched to receive an output with the high resolution like described in:

> -ps pixelsize_x pixelsize_y
>   Pixel size to be used for the output file. If not specified the resolution of the first input file will be used.

using the command:

`/usr/bin/gdal_merge.py -o /home/Workspace/output.tif srtm_38_03.tif 30N000E_20101117_gmted_mea075.tif`

results in the following error:

```
0...10...20...30...40...50ERROR 2: gdalnodatamaskband.cpp, 244: cannot allocate 3456000000 bytes
[1]    19672 segmentation fault (core dumped)  /usr/bin/gdal_merge.py -o /home/Workspace/output.tif
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible to realize what I want to do?

Comment: This is only possible if the pixel dimensions of the lower resolution image are evenly divisible by the  higher resolution image (e.g. 3 arc-second and 1 arc-second DEMs). Since your larger dimension is 2.5 times the smaller, you'd need to oversample the higher resolution image to four times the volume (2x2), then oversample the lower resolution image to 25 times the volume (5x5) before you could cleanly mosaic them at a pixel size of 0.0004166666666667. I'll leave corner alignment as a an exercise.